# Meaning of literal_only_boolean_expressions lint rule

Tags: dart, lint

What does [literal_only_boolean_expressions](http://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/literal_only_boolean_expressions.html) lint rule means? Example looks like it is just case, when boolean expression composed of language literals only, but why this code fails?

```
bool isNullOrEmpty(Iterable value) {
    if (value?.isEmpty??true) // Conditions should not unconditionally evaluate to "TRUE" or to "FALSE"
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Might be a false positive. The linter rule was just introduced and it's likely that it's not yet perfect.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is it the reason why it marked `(stable)` in lint rules? :)

Comment: `(stable)` is subjective and you can never be sure there are no bugs.